# What is the role of NASM programming in Malware Analysis

Tags: nasm, reverse-engineering, malware-detection

I have been heard about Reverse Engineering.Its quite interesting and little tough too.Recently I came to know that Kali Linux OS has a NASM shell which comes under the category of Reverse Engineering.Can anybody give a detailed description of how Netwide Assembler programe makes a role in detecting Malwares.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a reverse engineering question rather than a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

NASM is not a programming language, it is an [assembler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language#Assembler). A pretty  well known and good one. Basically assembers are tools used to convert assembly language to machine byte code, but usually they provide some additional related functionality to assist in creating executables and other related tasks.

Assembers are not really particularity related to reverse engineering, but this is probably the most common use case in the field of security.

If you're interested in reverse engineering I would like to invite you to the reverse engineering stack exchange long beta site, at [reverseengineering.stackexchange.com](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com)